# Does PLS have a corresponding objective function to PCA's?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, partial-least-squares

Paraphrased from *Understanding Machine Learning* by Shalev-Shwartz:

> Let $\mathbf{x}_1, \dots, \mathbf{x}_m \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $\mathbf{W}$
>   an $n \times d$ matrix with real entries, and $\mathbf{U}$ a $d \times n$ matrix with real entries, with $n < d$. The principal component analysis (PCA)
>   problem entails finding $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{W}$ which
>   minimize the loss function \begin{equation}
>  \sum_{i=1}^{m}\|\mathbf{x}_i -
> \mathbf{U}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}_i\|^{2}_{2}\text{.} \end{equation}

What is the corresponding objective funtion for partial least squares (PLS), if there is one? From what I'm getting from *Introduction to Statistical Learning* (ISL) by James et al. (anyone who's read this book would know it doesn't go into much mathematical detail), my guess would be if $y_1, \dots, y_m\in \mathbb{R}$, the objective function is finding the $n \times d$ matrix $\mathbf{V}$ and the $n \times 1$ matrix $\boldsymbol\beta$ which minimize
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left[y_i-(\mathbf{V}\mathbf{x}_i)^{T}\boldsymbol\beta\right]^{2}$$
since ISL states:

> Like PCR, PLS is a dimension reduction method, which first identifies a new set of features $Z_1, \dots, Z_M$ $(M$ corresponding to $n$ in this case) that are linear combinations of the original features, and then fits a linear model via least squares using these $M$ new features.

Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: In your formulation, what stops you from reducing it to a typical regression problem by defining $\gamma \equiv V^T\beta$?

Comment: @eric_kernfeld Ah, that's an excellent point. And I'm completely with you, PLS is extremely confusing. It took me going through 4 books to understand the theory behind PCA, and I can't find any mention of PLS other than in the Stanford texts (ISL, Elements of Statistical Learning).

Comment: I'm going to list some references to PLS questions here on CV. Have you looked at these?

[Q1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23353/pca-lda-cca-and-pls)
[Q2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300904/dimensionality-reduction-interpretation)
[Q3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206997/probabilistic-models-for-partial-least-squares-reduced-rank-regression-and-can)
[Q4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206587/what-is-the-connection-between-partial-least-squares-reduced-rank-regression-a/206883#206883)

Comment: Also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179733