# Decomposition of vector into product of a function on a matrix and a function on a vector - Possible?

Tags: machine-learning, least-squares, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Say I have access to $N$-dim vector $Y$, $N \times p$ matrix $X$, and $q$-dim vector $Z$.

Ultimately, I would like to learn the functions $g,f$ in: $\underset{N\times1}{\underbrace{Y}}=\underset{N\times K}{\underbrace{f\left(X\right)}}\underset{K\times1}{\underbrace{g\left(Z\right)}}$

I'm open for anything. My initial idea was a two-step approach:

1. Assume knowledge of $f(X)$. Rewrite equation to get: $\underset{K\times1}{\underbrace{\left(f\left(X\right)'f\left(X\right)\right)^{-1}f\left(X\right)'Y}}=\underset{K\times1}{\underbrace{g\left(Z\right)}}$, and learn $g$ from $q$-dim vector $Z$.
2. Assume knowledge of $g(Z)$. Rewrite equation to get: $\underset{N\times K}{\underbrace{Yg\left(Z\right)'\left(g\left(Z\right)g\left(Z\right)'\right)^{-1}}}=\underset{N\times K}{\underbrace{f\left(X\right)}}$, and then learn $f$ from $N \times p$ matrix $X$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume this is a lease square estimation problem

Comment: Would you go with a two-step vector regression approach then or did you have something more elaborate in mind?

Comment: And how would you solve step 1? You have only a $K$-vector of responses and a $q$-vector of inputs.

Comment: Could you explain what "access to" might mean?  If you observe just one instance of $Z,$ then there's no hope of learning $g(Z).$

Comment: In a cross-section, I observe only one instance of $Z$. That being said, I kind of suspect the $f$ and $g$ will not be identified, only their product - which is perfectly fine. So, I just have to find one pair $f,g$ where this holds. In addition, I have access to a time-series as well $T$. So I observe $N \times p$ matrix $X$ and $q$-dim vector $Z$ for every point in time, $t = {1, ..., T}$. If it's possible to solve the problem using the time-series dimension as sell, that would be good. But for every $t$ would also be good.

Comment: This sounds like an overly complicated formulation of nonlinear multiple regression.  $Z$ and $g$ look superfluous, because everything can be accommodated in the function $f.$  Nonlinear multiple regression encompasses just about all of machine learning as well as a good part of statistics, so consider refining your question!  At a minimum, you need to supply some context in order to keep this from being too broad.

Comment: The thing is that I need both $f(X)$ and $g(Z)$ to test a model afterwards. It's kind of a technical paper in economics, so that's why it's very narrowly defined. I managed to solve it using a multivariate extension to both recursive least squares (step 1) and random forest (step 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I'm gathering it sounds like a lease square estimation problem, for each case you can obtain your solution by minimizing the following:

$\text{arg}\,\min\limits_{g\left(Z\right)}\,(Y-f\left(X\right)g\left(Z\right))(Y-f\left(X\right)g\left(Z\right))'$

$\text{arg}\,\min\limits_{f\left(X\right)}\,tr((Y-f\left(X\right)g\left(Z\right))(Y-f\left(X\right)g\left(Z\right))')$

If $f$ or $g$ is linear there is a closed-form solution your solution looks correct to verify page 11:[The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). Just a note $(f\left(X\right)'f\left(X\right))$ should be full rank but thats not always the case in practice.

Comment: Thanks! I see why this works in step (2) of the initial two-step approach. However, I'm still not convinced it would work in step (1). For clarity, we are trying to fit a $K$-dim vector to a $q$-dim vector, assuming $q>K$. Will least squares give you this?

Comment: I think equation 83 in the reference has that case (for the linear case)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not completely sure what you are referring to (I'm looking up Eq. 83, but don't quite follow the connection). Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Assuming my minimization formula is correct,I believe equation 119 is the solution to step 1 as there is a trace operator and the result will be a scaler  and equation  83 is the solution to step 2. You will need to do some basic manipulation  so its in the same form as the book obtain the derivative and set it to zeros to get the solution